# Inject a web component with Chrome Extension using Stencil

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, web-component, stenciljs

Im using stencil as my web components library to inject components to websites using chrome extension content script, Im injecting the needed scripts, But on some sites like bard.google.com
Im getting a TrustedType Error `Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML` seems that stencil script is using innerHTML which is legit but I cant find a way to pass it.

1. Tried to implment window.trustedTypes.createPolicy didnt worked
2. Tried to use a stencil/webpack plugin to import the components to the extension and render them using the plugin but the plugin is depracted and not suitable to webpack 5 (my extension is bundled using webpack 5)

Answer (score 0):

TrustedType enforcement is done via CSP header, specifically `Content-Security-Policy: require-trusted-types-for 'script'`.

You can modify a header using `declarativeNetRequest`.

It would look something like this

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
    removeRuleIds: [99],
    addRules: [{
      id: 99,
      priority: 1,
      action: {
        type: 'modifyHeaders',
        responseHeaders: [
          {
            header: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            operation: 'remove'
          }
        ],
      },
      condition: {
        urlFilter: 'https://bard.google.com/*',
        resourceTypes: ['main_frame'] 
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

You can find a specific example of removing CSP headers using dnr [here](https://github.com/WithoutHair/Disable-Content-Security-Policy)